# jQuery Waypoints plugin fade in elements one by one

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-waypoints

I am using the waypoints jQuery plugin and the plugin behaves perfectly when doing the fade in on scroll. Yet, I cannot manage to make the blocks fade in one after the other (individually). Here's my jQuery code:

```
$('.hblock').not("#welcome, #block2").fadeTo(0, 0);
$('.hblock').waypoint(function(event, direction) {
    if(direction == "down") {
        $(this).fadeTo(1500, 1);
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
}, {
    offset: function() {
        return $.waypoints('viewportHeight');
    }
});
```

I have tried setting a delay between the fades, but to no avail:

```
$(this).fadeTo(1500, 1).delay(1000);
```

You can see the plugin in action and how it currently works, here: http://targettedmedia.co.uk/targetedmedia/

Thank you in advance for taking your time!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to serially animate a group of objects so instead of `$(this).fadeTo(1500, 1);`

Try this:

```
$('.hblock').each(function(i) {
    $(this).delay((i++) * 1500).fadeTo(1500, 1); 
 })
```

You can experiment with the first 1500 if you want them to start before the prior one finishes.  Here is an example (towards bottom):

http://demosthenes.info/blog/630/Fade-In-Elements-Sequentially-With-JQuery-amp-CSS3

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this

```
function _fadeout(elm){
    elm.fadeOut('slow', function(){
       _fadeout(elm.next());
    })
}

_fadeout($('.hblock').not("#welcome, #block2").first());
```

Comment: This hides it completely. Also, please note that I'm trying to achieve a succinct fade in effect, not viceversa (fade out).